# How test if request allow "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" on AbstractGuardAuthenticator::support()

Tags: symfony, security

I have the following code:

My config/security.yml

```
security:
    ...

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
        - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: lazy
            stateless: false
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\CasAuthenticator
            ...
```

My App\Security\CasAuthenticator :

```
class CasAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        $isAuthenticatedAnonymouslyAllowed = ???????;

        if ($isAuthenticatedAnonymouslyAllowed && !\phpCAS::isAuthenticated()) { 
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return \phpCAS::forceAuthentication();
    }

    ...
}
```

How can i easily test if access control allow IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY on my method ?

Comment: Why don't you mock the behaviour ?

Comment: can you give me an exemple ?

Comment: ok submit your test case first.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use the following annotation you can test it.

@Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')")

This should for as far as I know only allow non authenticated users to use your methods.

For more info you might want to take a look at this link.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/best_practices/security.html

Comment: You don't answer to my question.

Comment: FreezeBee please explain what makes this not the answer. Because I'm sure this is the answer or I'm missing information if it is not.

Comment: @FreezeBee please notify me if something about your question changed because I only see at my screen the question asking how to check access control for a single method, that is also the question which I provided the answer to.